# Swift compiler "Fix It" error loop - Optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

Swift's "Fix It" tool is complaining that an exclamation point is needed. After inserting one, it complains that it needs to be removed. What is the correct usage of "?" and "!" for this code?!

```
var debugLabel : SKLabelNode!

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    debugLabel!.text = "Ang:  \(getFormattedNum(ball.physicsBody?.angularVelocity! ))"
}

func getFormattedNum( num:CGFloat ) ->String {
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(num)!
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    debugLabel = childNodeWithName("deBugger") as SKLabelNode
   ...
}
```

The place Fix It is toggling back and forth is the exclamation point at the end of this property in the update func:
   ball.physicsBody?.angularVelocity!

With ! or ? the error is "Operand of postfix ! should have optional type; type is "CGFloat".

Without optional indicator the error is "Value of optional type "CGFloat?" not unwrapped...

Note that "deBugger" is the name of a label in the sks.

Comment: ball is a ColorSprite on sks defined as: 
 var ball   :SKSpriteNode!

Comment: `angularVelocity` is declared as `var angularVelocity: CGFloat` according to Apple documentation, so the exclamation point isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but why does Xcode tell me it is? Am I declaring something wrong?

Comment: vacawama's answer explains that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an optional chain `ball.physicsBody?.angularVelocity`.  This is going result in an optional because it is an optional chain.  Unfortunately, you can't just unwrap that by adding a `!` to the end because `ball.physicsBody?.angularVelocity!` is also an optional chain (the `!` only unwraps the `angularVelocity` and not the entire chain). Also, in this case, `angularVelocity` is of type `CGFloat` so you can't unwrap it.  You need to add parenthesis around the optional chain and then you can unwrap it:

```
debugLabel!.text = "Ang:  \(getFormattedNum((ball.physicsBody?.angularVelocity)! ))"
```